# What is the gritty storylines?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Kojak starred Telly Savalas as the bald-headed, lollipop-sucking New York City policeman Lieutenant Theo Kojak. The reason that Kojak loved lollipops was because Savalas was a heavy smoker, and in the face of growing anti-smoking feeling in the USA he decided to suck on a lollipop instead. This became his trademark and, along with charisma and humour, it lightened the **gritty storylines**.

Comment: Gritty, "showing or having a lot of unpleasant details or features", see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gritty

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a dictionary for this, although to be fair "gritty" does have multiple meanings. In this context, it means "showing something unpleasant as it really is; uncompromising". A "gritty" story, such as a novel, movie or TV show is usually very "dark" in tone - very serious, often humourless to maintain that tone, and may be quite graphic either visually or psychologically.

In your example, the text is suggesting that the TV series *Kojak* had "gritty" storylines and subject matter, but that there were lighter elements that acted as a contrast, so it was not entirely humourless.